# can't control the brightness of display on ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, brightness, backlight

I just installed Ubuntu 16.04 in my labtop.

But the problem is that the monitor is too dim&dark and I can't make the display brighter as the brightness control slider is not shown.

https://www.maketecheasier.com/assets/uploads/2012/11/brightness-adjust-level.png

normally, the slider in the red box has to be shown.

But, that control slider in the red box is not shown in my situation.

I browsed several solutions such as using

sudo apt-get install brightness-controller

or

grub editing with "acpi_backlight=vendor"

but, none of them solved my problem.

I also tried to editing the folder /sys/class/backlight , but, that folder is empty in my computer while the solution example says that there's something such as intel_backlight.

does anyone can help me for brighter developing environment?

I'm not sure that using gtx 960m as GPU, i5-6300hq as CPU is useful info....

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't comment, here's a question or potential answer: can you try `echo 200 | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness`? Perhaps you didn't check `/sys/class/backlight` as root.

Comment: noting exists when I use "ls /sys/class/backlight" at terminal